# Using template literal for dynamic property in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

My failed attempt:

```
temp.map((obj,i) => ({ 
    obj[`person${++i}`] = obj.person.name
})
```

I want to produce something like this

```
[{id:324, person1:'mike'},{id:23, person2:'jane'}]
```

But I'm stuck on making the property dynamic with concatenation using template literal string.

Comment: What does your input look like? are you trying to modify `temp` or create a new object?

Comment: @PilotInPyjamas just assume temp is an array of object, it doesn't matter, my question is how to contruct dynamic property in a loop using es6 string literal.

Comment: @CeciliaChan you want to make the changes in original data or want to create new array?

Comment: Not the problem, but **don't use `.map()` unless you want to create a new array:** if you just want to iterate over the existing array to modify the objects in it use `.forEach()`.

Comment: It does too matter!  For us to show you the appropriate way to convert one data structure to another, we need to see BOTH input and output structures.  We do a LOT better here with specific questions that show exactly what you're trying to do than general questions where we have to guess what you're trying to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue with you code is, you are directly returning the data by using

`() => ({....})`

and there you are using `obj[...]` that is not a valid key.

---

`map` return the a new array so store the result in a new variable, if you want to modify the same array then better to use `forEach`.

Check this snippet:

```js
let arr = [{id: 10, name: 'A'}, {id: 20, name: 'B'}];

let newArr = arr.map((el,i) => ({
    id: el.id,
    [`name${i+1}`]: el.name
}));

console.log('new array', newArr);
```

Modifying the same data using `forEach`:

```js
let arr = [{id: 10, name: 'A'}, {id: 20, name: 'B'}];

arr.forEach((el,i) => {
   el[`person${i+1}`] = el.name;
})

console.log('modified array', arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var myInput = ["John", "Jane", "Steven", "Alice"];

var myOutput = myInput.map ((name, index) => {
  var out = {};
  out[`person${index}`] = name;
  return out;
}); // myOutput is [{person1:"John"}, {person2:"Jane"} ... etc.
```

`map` creates a new array rather than modifying the existing one. The values of the array are made out of the return values of the function, so if you want your values to be objects, you must create new objects and then assign your properties to them.

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
describe("sample test", () => {
  it("Dynamic property in ES6", () => {
    const temp = [
      { id: 324, person: { name: "mike" } },
      { id: 23, person: { name: "jane" } }
    ];
    console.log(
      temp.map((obj, i) => ({
        id: obj.id,
        [`person${i + 1}`]: obj.person.name
      }))
    );
  });
});
```

Output:

```
[ { id: 324, person1: 'mike' }, { id: 23, person2: 'jane' } ]
```

Comment: The question asked for this output: `[{id:324,person1:'mike'},{id:23,person2:'jane'}] `

Comment: @nnnnnn - just edited the code to use the exact data in and produce the exact data out mentioned in the  question.